# Is my ddr3 RAM compatible with my pc?

Tags: memory, compatibility

i have a shuttle barebone pc (link to description: http://www.shuttle.eu/fileadmin/resources/download/docs/spec/barebones/SG41J1_Plus_black_e.pdf). I would add some RAM, but i don't know if the one i want to buy is compatible (DDR3 1333 MHz 2gb 10600). Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Nope.

It supports DDR3 but of speeds 800MHz to 1066MHZ.
Those sticks might work, but as those reduced speeds.

Also make sure you don't already have the 2 slots occupied. if so, you will have to replace the actual sticks.